# create element at index position if index does not exist in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array objects that hold an id and a name

```
const stages = [{
  id: 1,
  name: ''
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: ''
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: ''
}, {
  id: 4,
  name: ''
}, {
  id: 5,
  name: ''
}, {
  id: 6,
  name: ''
}, {
  id: 7,
  name: ''
}, {
  id: 8,
  name: ''
}];
```

Further I have an array that holds numbers.

```
const indexPositions = [0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 0];
```

I want to create a third array that holds arrays. Each number in `distances` represents the index of the current array within the array.

If the current array does not exist yet I want to create it first. Obviously I have to create new arrays until I get to this index position.

Example:
My array is empty at start. The first index position is 0 so I have to create a new array for this. The next index position is 3 so I have to create more arrays until I have 4 arrays.

All I want to do is to push the stage to its correct level index position. The result of this example would be

```
const levels = [
  [stage1, stage8],
  [stage2],
  [stage3, stage4, stage5, stage7],
  [stage6]
];
```

Currently my code looks this

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  const levels = []; // the array containing the arrays

  stages.forEach((stage, stageIndex) => {
    const indexPosition = indexPositions[stageIndex];

    const positionDifference = indexPosition - levels.length;

    if (positionDifference > 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i < positionDifference; i++) { // fill up with empty arrays
        levels.push([]);
      }
    }

    levels[indexPosition].push(stage);
  });
});
```

I get this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` and this happens because the indexPosition is out of bounds. If the `positionDifference` is 0 no array gets created but in the beginning the array is empty.

I tried setting `levels.length` to -1 if it is 0 but I still get the error if the difference is 1, I create one array at position 0 and want to access position 1.

How can I create an empty array if it does not exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I do not fully understand what you want to do, checking existence of an array element is simple, one way of doing that is coercing it to boolean:

```js
const thing=[];
function addElem(where,what){
  if(!thing[where])              // <- here
    thing[where]=[];
  thing[where].push(what);
}

addElem(2,1);
addElem(2,2);
addElem(2,3);
addElem(5,1);
console.log(thing);
```

(The indices are deliberately non-continuous, because that does not matter: JavaScript arrays are sparse)

Comment: oh well, this looks easy

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single loop and add an array for the index if not exists. Then push the wanted value.

```js
var stages = [{ id: 1, name: '' }, { id: 2, name: '' }, { id: 3, name: '' }, { id: 4, name: '' }, { id: 5, name: '' }, { id: 6, name: '' }, { id: 7, name: '' }, { id: 8, name: '' }],
    indexPositions = [0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 0],
    result = stages.reduce((r, o, i) => {
        var index = indexPositions[i];
        r[index] = r[index] || [];     // take default value for falsy value
        r[index].push('stage' + o.id); // instead of string take object
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually were very close! You have a very small issue in your code.

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  const levels = []; // the array containing the arrays

  stages.forEach((stage, stageIndex) => {
    const indexPosition = indexPositions[stageIndex];

    const positionDifference = indexPosition - levels.length + 1; //YOU DID NOT ADD 1 HERE

    if (positionDifference > 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i < positionDifference; i++) { // fill up with empty arrays
        levels.push([]);
      }
    }

    levels[indexPosition].push(stage);
  });
});
```

When you were calculating the positionDifference, you did not add 1 causing the problem when indexPosition equaled 0 and the for loop did not run and no new arrays were pushed. Just adding one fixed the problem :-)